# Getting error with DBCP Pool: "java.sql.SQLException: Configuration file not found"

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

I am getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Configuration file not found
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver.getConnectionPool(PoolingDriver.java:137)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver.connect(PoolingDriver.java:175)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at com.test.sql.Test.main(Model.java:95)
```

I checked the connection and there's nothing wrong with it. It's just a pool error. If I don't use the pool but open a connection directly (using the `connectionFactory` below), I can connect and execute a statement and get a result set.

The code to create and use the pool:

```
    AbandonedConfig cfg = new AbandonedConfig ();
    cfg.setLogAbandoned (true);
    cfg.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout (5);
    cfg.setRemoveAbandoned (true);
    GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new AbandonedObjectPool(null, cfg);
    connectionPool.setTestWhileIdle (true);
    connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow (true);
    connectionPool.setTestOnReturn (true);
    connectionPool.setMaxActive (5);
    connectionPool.setMaxWait (5000);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?user=testuser&password=password",null);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory,connectionPool,null,null,false,true, cfg);
    poolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQuery ("SELECT 1");

    Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver");
    PoolingDriver driver = (PoolingDriver) DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:");
    driver.registerPool("test_pool",connectionPool);


    //This throws the error
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:" );

    //This does too
    //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:Test" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how I was asking for a connection. You need to ask it for your pool underneath Apache's driver URL:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( 
     "jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:test_pool"
);
```

So the format is:

```
"jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:" + TheNameOfYourPool
```